# Load ML model (.pkl) and use in local

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, local, machine-learning-model

I have trained the ML model in Azure machine learning, and I hope not to deploy it to an endpoint. Instead, I hope to load the model and run it in my local machine to predict the result.

I got these files downloaded from Azure as shown below. So, what should I do to load the model and do the prediction? Do all these 3 files are required to use, or only the .pkl file is needed?

[image]

Comment: Could you please refer this MS DOC : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-local ,may it helps

Answer (score 0):

We can target local machines for deploying our models which are created in Azure Machine Learning.

In your case we need to use docker image as it provides isolated, containerized experience.

Below are the steps to deploy as local web service using Docker:

1. Connect to the Azure Machine Learning workspace in which your model is registered.
2. Create a  `Model`  object that represents the model.
3. Create an  `Environment`  object that contains the dependencies and defines the software environment in which your code will run.
4. Create an  `InferenceConfig`  object that associates the entry script with the  `Environment`.
5. Create a  `DeploymentConfiguration`  object of the subclass  `LocalWebserviceDeploymentConfiguration`.
6. Use  `Model.deploy()`  to create a  `Webservice`  object. This method downloads the Docker image and associates it with the  `Model`,  `InferenceConfig`, and  `DeploymentConfiguration`.
7. Activate the  `Webservice`  by using  `Webservice.wait_for_deployment()`.

Refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-local) as AjayKumarGhose suggested. Also check this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-train-models-with-aml) for training an image model